# Fragment's onActivityResult not called after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes

Please note, this question is not a duplicate of the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006776/onactivityresult-not-working-with-fragments
- [onActivityResult not working on fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005193/onactivityresult-not-working-on-fragments)

Also, another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270594/activity-result-no-fragment-exists-for-index-after-facebook-publish) was asked before, but that doesn't mention orientation changes (and is unresolved).

My `onActivityResult` method in the `Fragment` does get called if I don't switch orientation. However, if I follow these steps, it doesn't get called:

1. Load fragment in FragmentActivity.
2. From the fragment: `startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), Constants.REQ_CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`
3. Wait for the camera to load.
4. Switch orientation.
5. Take picture and click the checkmark.

`onActivityResult` still gets called in the parent FragmentActivity. However, due to this warning I am getting:

```
W/FragmentActivity(4418): Activity result no fragment exists for index: 0x22d73
```

...my guess is that the parent gets destroyed due to the orientation change, and after having been re-created, can't find the `Fragment` that called `startActivityForResult` in the first place.

Is this a framework bug? How can this be worked around?

**EDIT**: Added more code due to popular demand.

**FragmentActivity.java:**

```
...

fragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace (R.id.mainContentView, fragment);
if (clearBackStack) {
    // clear the back stack
    while (getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate ());
    // add the current transaction to the back stack
    transaction.addToBackStack (null);
}
else {
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
transaction.commit();

...

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**ExampleFragment.java:**

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, Constants.REQ_CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

...

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case Constants.REQ_CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
        // handle added image
    }
}
```

Comment: There is issue in support library. Check this post: http://shomeser.blogspot.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html

Comment: @shomeser, your post came up when searching for something, but I have no nested fragments, so I don't think it's related.

Comment: index of your fragment is too big: 0x22d73, it looks like something strange happened. is this issue stable to reproduce? could you show your code?

Comment: @shomeser, there is nothing really special about my code, but see the edit. The issue is always reproducible if you follow the provided steps.

Comment: Did you try to move invocation of popBackStackImmediate() before beginTransaction() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it by moving all of the `onActivityResult` logic from the `Fragment` to the `Activity`.

**Do note**, however, that the `reqCode` that gets passed to the `Fragment` is different than the `reqCode` that gets delivered to the parent `Activity` (the one for the `Activity` is set by the system I think). This meant that I had to also move the original `startActivityForResult` call from the `Fragment` to the `Activity`, and then create a method to call it from the `Fragment` when needed.

If anyone finds a more elegant way, I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: See method FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(), it modifies original request code to store index of Fragment: http://goo.gl/yuaPWW That's why you got different value. Sad, but currently I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: That fix worked for me. The issue occurred only on some devices (Galaxy S5 was fine, but I had the error on Sony XPeria)

Comment: On my situation, the onActivityResult was on my Activity class already. But I still notice the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

i Have one Solution
it is currently Working in my project.
follow Step.

--> Create Interface name OnActivityResultListener(or name as you wish).

public interface OnActivityResultListener {

```
public boolean onActivityResultTest(int request_code, int response_code,
        Intent data);
```

}

--> Make refrence of intercace in your FragmentActivity like

```
public OnActivityResultListener activityResultListener;
```

--> now override OnActivityResult in FragmentActivity. like below.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    AppLog.Log(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    try {
        if (activityResultListener != null) {
            activityResultListener.onActivityResultTest(arg0,arg1,arg2);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
```

--> now implement interface in your Fragment and override required method.

```
@Override
public boolean onActivityResultTest(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    AppLog.Log(TAG, "onActivityResultTest");
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        isHavePhoto = true;
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        userEditPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

--> and the last step is inside OnAttach Method of Fragment class is register your Fragment in activity for the the Activity result. like

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = (YOUR_FRAGMENT_ACTIVITY) activity;
            this.activity.activityResultListener = this;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }
```

-->now test and don't forgot to remove it

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    activity.activityResultListener = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

->it is some what lengthy process but it is working 100% in any orientation.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 4.4, Nexus 5, revision 19.0.1 of the support library. The fragment gets attached after the Activity's `onActivityResult` gets called, so at the time it gets called, the listener is null.

Comment: sorry but it is working with 4.4 i have tested in Nexus 4 and 5 too it is working. you need to tell me i think you have problem with onAttach method.check for the all step again.

Comment: Well, that could be. However, in my current situation, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Works fine, just `startActivityForResult` have to be called from the activity (`activity?.startActivityForResult`)