# Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, fragmentmanager, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using [navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) in `MainActivity`, then I start `SecondActivity` (for result). After finish of `SecondActivity` I would like to continue with navigation in `MainActivity`, but `FragmentManager` has saved his state already.

On `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_next, bundle)` I receive log message:

```
Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state
```

How I can continue in navigation?

Comment: Where are you calling the navigate method from?

Comment: @Chris I call `navigate` from `Fragment` of first `Activity`, when `onActivityResult` is called in the parent `Activity`.

Comment: Have you tried calling startActivityForResult and overriding onActivityResult in the Fragment directly?

Comment: @Chris yes, i tried, but there is problem when first activity is restarted (orientation change) during processing second activity (result is not called on fragment of restarted activity)

Comment: How are you triggering the navigate call in the fragment? If you're consuming the result in the Activity can you not just navigate directly from there - e.g. by using something like Navigation.findNavController(this.findViewById(R.id.nav_host)) - where nav_host is your NavHostFragment

Comment: @Chris there is listener for result call in fragment used (so the result is promoted to the fragment). This solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21305578/4353365

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue @FrancisNovotný?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must always call `super.onActivityResult()` in your Activity's `onActivityResult`. That is what:

1. Unlocks Fragments so they can do fragment transactions (i.e., avoid the `state is already saved` errors)
2. Dispatches `onActivityResult` callbacks to Fragments that called `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: I've filed [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127971684) to track adding `@CallSuper` to `FragmentActivity`'s `onActivityResult`

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: Welp moving super.ondestroy to the top of the function solved a lot of things for me. Thank you dude!

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I fix the issue by simple calling `super.onPostResume()` right before navigating to restore state.

Comment: this helped me too

Comment: What do you mean by navigating to restore state, can you please clarify because i am also having similar issue but not sure where need to call this super.onPostResume()?

Comment: @francis Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 2):

I believe above solutions should work. But my problem was different. There was a third party sdk which was launching its activity using context provided by me and it was delivering the result on a listener which I had to implement.

So there was no option for me to work with `onActivityResult` :(

I used below hack to solve the issue:

```
   private var runnable: Runnable? = null // Runnable object to contain the navigation code

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // run any task waiting for this fragment to be resumed
        runnable?.run()
    }


    override fun responseListener(response: Response) {    // Function in which you are getting response

        if (!isResumed) {    
            // add navigation to runnable as fragment is not resumed
            runnable = Runnable {
                navController.navigate(R.id.destination_to_navigate)
            }
        } else {
            // navigate normally as fragment is already resumed
            navController.navigate(R.id.destination_to_navigate)
        }
    }
```

Let me know if there is any better solution for this. Currently I found this very simple and easy to implement :)

Comment: works nice, just add runnable = null after navigating in the Runnable block, otherwise you'll navigate at each app resume.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem this way:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult() { //inside my fragment that started activity for result
        model.navigateToResults = true; //set flag, that navigation should be performed
}
```

and then

```
    @Override
public void onResume() { //inside fragment that started activity for result
    super.onResume();

    if(model.navigateToResults){
        model.navigateToResults = false;
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_resultsFragment);
    }
}
```

not sure, if this is not a terrible hack, but it worked for me. FramgentManager state is restored at this point (onResume) and no problems with navigation occur.

Comment: I also experienced the problem when using a LiveData observable instead of onActivityResult to communicate navigation events between an Activity and another Activity with Fragments. The solution to perform navigation in onResume worked perfectly

Comment: There's no way since using navigation component in android < 21. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

call super.onPostResume() before navigation....It's working

Comment: Hi shashank, this answer has already been posted nearly word for word [by the original question poster.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233051/5373986)